# Are there any applications for editing 2d Schlegel diagrams and then projecting them back onto a 3d polyhedron?

Tags: polyhedra

I'm trying to create some (hopefully) interesting polyhedra with Robert Webb's Great Stella / Stella 4D, but even its power users seem to only be able to do this kind of thing indirectly (or via importing .off or .dxf files), whereas I'd like to do this more directly.

For example, are there any apps out there that can edit 2d Schlegel diagrams and then make a reasonable attempt at projecting them back onto the surface of a sphere (or nearly)?